# WP_Query: Modify array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, filter

I have managed to integrate a custom taxonomies plugin that:

-Filters down the staff depending on what category is selected.

I want it to show **that department first**, and then the other departments beneath rather than that department all on its own (how it is now).

Here is the link:
http://crippslawtest.co.uk/people/

Here is my Wordpress loop:

```
        <div class="staffwrapper">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cripps_staff', 'posts_per_page' => 300 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    echo '<div class="col-md-3 spacetop">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo '<img src="';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'image',true);
    echo '">';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffname">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_name',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffrole">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_role',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffnumber">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_telephone_number',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffemail">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_email_address',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </div><!--End of staff wrapper-->
```

On the results page (search-people.php) I have added a second WP Query using info from this link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties

This is meant to show all the other posts available. I need the array of $args2 that is: "show all the rest of posts in my staff members custom posts"

Here is my attempt:

```
                    //2nd loop
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $args2 = array( 
            'post_type' => 'cripps_staff',
            'posts_per_page' => '300'

    );
    $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
    while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->next_post();
    echo '<div class="col-md-3 spacetop">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo '<img src="';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'image',true);
    echo '">';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffname">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_name',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffrole">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_role',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffnumber">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_telephone_number',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffemail">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_email_address',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '</div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

This is creating duplications on my results page, the same post is repeated 6 times! It has taken me ages to get this far, help please :S It should display "all the other posts from Cripps_Staff"

After hours of research, I know it is something to do with adding a double array to my search-people.php that is like:

```
        $args2 = array( 
            'post_type' => 'cripps_staff',
            'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Department',
        'terms' => array( 'accounting', 'Corporate' )
    ),
            array(
        'taxonomy' => 'role',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
)
    );
```

But I can't for the life of me work out how to organize it properly, any ideas? ANy Wordpress evangelists out there?

I tried this, it is very close!!! What is it retrieving ?

```
    $args2 = array( 
        'post_type' => 'cripps_staff',
        'tax_query'          => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Department',   
        'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
    )
)

);
```

Comment: Please see my answer to your [exact same question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143071/31545) on WPSE

Answer (score 2):

I'd make **2 queries**, one for the current department and one for the others (excluding the current).

Alternatively, since `$loop` is an object containing all the query results, you could extract and remove the current department from there.

Of course in the Codex you can find all the details on how to filter queries:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Also, I suggest you don't repeat `get_post_meta` and instead use `get_post_custom`: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: I have updated my code with an attempt for my second query but I am still struggling... My php is a bit rusty. I think it is something like : $args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'cripps_staff', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
  $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
  // The 2nd Loop
  while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
  $query2->next_post();
  echo '<div class="col-md-3 spacetop">'; ...etc

Comment: Is it something like this in the array? "array(
    'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts');
);"

Comment: I think you should filter your second array with the department value... like if i select accounting than it will show the 2 results from first array than in second array just use find the department tag == accounting if it says true than do not add this to your second loop else add it

Comment: @Vivek Would you kindly provide me with the code value that I should put inside the array? It would be much appreciated as no one here (even the head of dev!) can help, just this bit:                                                                             $args2 = array( 
            'post_type' => 'cripps_staff',
            'posts_per_page' => '300',--------?

Comment: @ArchieButler I dont know how wordpress works and I just know the logic only if you are need it outside wordpress or cms than i can provide you